# partial geometry example

Tags: geometry

I am studying partial geometry for my project. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_geometry) is the definition of partial geometry. I try to understand what is going on by constructing an example but I fail to do so. Can anyone help me to construct one example which satisfies the definition of partial geometry?